# JPEG file wont open in QGIS 3.10 but does in QGIS 3.4

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-3, jpg

I recently made the upgrade to QIGS 3.10 from 3.4 and I am having trouble loading a JPEG image that previously worked fine in 3.4. In the georeference window when I try to open the raster I am given the following error:

D:/DJI_0151.JPG is not a supported raster data source.
libjpeg: Bogus marker length

If I try to open it as a raster in the map I get the error 'unable to open GDAL dataset'

It is funny because some JPEGS seem to work fine and some don't now when previously they all worked fine.

Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Can you supply a download link to a jpg that works in 3.4 but not 3.10?  This would let others investigate, rather than taking a guess.

Comment: If we need to guess, the newer libjpeg version finds some issues in your images that the older version did not. Either there is an issue in libjpeg, or in the images.